# Selenium WebDriver findElement

Tags: selenium, xpath, webdriver

I am trying to make an event click on this input?

If i specify the class name nothing is happening...

```
<input value="kerko" class="az-btn az-btn-block az-btn-primary" type="submit">
```

Comment: Are there multiple elements with this class name ?

Comment: yes, that why i have some difficulty

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using java, this code might work out for you:-

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@class, 'az-btn') and @value='kerko']")).click();
```

OR, Simply use the attribute 'value'.

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='kerko']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can be more specific with cssSelector, providing all parameters:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[class='az-btn az-btn-block az-btn-primary'][type='submit'][value='kerko']")).click();
```